# How to display tooltip for each column of a list in the datasheet view in sharepoint 2010

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, sharepoint-designer

I have a `list` in sharepoint with some columns like

```
Name | Job Description | Location

xxxx      xxxxxxx          xxxxx
aaa        aaaaa            aaa
```

I require this list to be displayed in `Datasheet View`, which i have done. 
While creating this list, i added a description for each column, is there anyway to show it as a `tooltip` when the user hovers over each column? Can this be done using sharepoint/sharepoint designer?

Comment: I'd be fine with adding a separate tooltip apart from the description of the column as well.

Answer (score 0):

IF...it is possible.  I would use SharePoint designer to insert JQuery on the dataview ASPX page, then call web services to get each column description, then bind tooltips on each column header in the dataview.

This is just a theory.

Comment: thanks for the answer, but it would be really helpful if i could get a more practical solution as I'm fairly new to SharePoint.